# awk to adjust coordinates of matching field using sequential numbers of another

Tags: awk

I am trying to output a tab-delimited result that uses the data from a tab-delimited file to combine and subtract specific lines.

If `$4` matches in each line then the first matching sequential `$6` value is added to `$2`, unless the value is `1`, then the original `$2` is used (like in the case of line 1). This is the new or adjusted `$2` value.

The last matching sequential `$6` value is added to `$2` and this is the new or adjusted `$3` value.

The new `$2` and `$3` vales are combined with `$1` in the format `$1`:`$2`-`$3` and the `$5` value is printed on the line.

The `awk` command below works great as long as the `$4` values are unique, but that is not always the case. I can not seem to add in a condition
that checks `$6` and if the numbers are not sequential (1 2 is, but then there is a break between 92 93 94), when there is a break a new line.

Maybe there is another way but hopefully this helps.  Thank you :)

**file**

```
chrX    110956442   110956535   chrX:110956442-110956535    ALG13   1   19
chrX    110956442   110956535   chrX:110956442-110956535    ALG13   2   19
chrX    110956442   110956535   chrX:110956442-110956535    ALG13   92  18
chrX    110956442   110956535   chrX:110956442-110956535    ALG13   93  18
chrX    110956442   110956535   chrX:110956442-110956535    ALG13   94  18
chrX    110961329   110961512   chrX:110961329-110961512    ALG13   2   1
chrX    110961329   110961512   chrX:110961329-110961512    ALG13   3   1
chrX    25031028    25031925    chrX:25031028-25031925  ARX 651 3
```

**desired output**

```
chrX:110956442-110956444    ALG13
chrX:110956534-110956536    ALG13
chrX:110961331-110961332    ALG13
chrx:25031679-25031679  ARX
```

awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR {S[$4]++;next} ($4 in S){if(S[$4]>1){print $1 OFS $2 OFS $2+S[$4] OFS $5;} 
else {if($6==1){print $1 OFS $2 OFS $2 OFS $5}
else {print $1 OFS $2+$6 OFS $2+$6 OFS $5}};delete S[$4]}' file file
```

**current output**

```
chrX 110956442 110956449 ALG13
chrX 110961329 110961334 ALG13
chrX 25031028 25031031 ARX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does most of what you want:

```
function myprint(start, first, last, key) {
    print "chrX:" (start + first) "-" (start + last) "\t" key;
}

NR == 1 {
    last_start = $2;
    key = $5;
    first_stop = $6;
    last_stop = $6;
    next;
}

{
    if ($2 == last_start) {
        if ($6 != (last_stop + 1)) {
            myprint(last_start, first_stop, last_stop, key);
            first_stop = $6;
        }
    } else {
        myprint(last_start, first_stop, last_stop, key);
        last_start = $2;
        first_stop = ($6 == 1) ? 0 : $6;
    }
    key = $5;
    last_stop = $6;
}

END {
    myprint(last_start, first_stop, last_stop, key);
}
```

However, it took me quite some time to understand your requirements, and I still do not understand why the second line of your desired output is `chrX:110956534-110956628    ALG13`, since `94 - 92 == 2`.

Comment: The original non-adjusted `$2` coordinate is `110956442` so `92` is added to this to give you the new adjusted `$2` coordinate of `110956534`. `94` is to the original non-adjusted `$2` coordinate to give you the new adjusted `$3` coordinate of `110956536`. The first sequential digit after a  break is added to `$2` and the last sequential digit before the break is added to `$2` in order to get the adjusted coordinates. Thank you very much :).

Comment: The `awk` is very close to perfect the only thing is line one which is `chrX:110956442-110956535`  should be adjusted to `chrX:110956442-110956444    ALG13` since `$6 == 1' the original `$1` value is used.  Thank you very much :).

Comment: currently it is `chrX:110956443-110956444 ALG13` and I thought the line to adjust was `first_stop = ($6 == 1) ? 0 : $6;`, but that doesn't seem to be it.  Thank you :).